# If $TM$ and $TN$ are diffeomorphic, then $M$ and $N$ are diffeomorphic.

Tags: smooth-manifolds

I want to prove following statement:

> If $TM$ and $TN$ are diffeomorphic, then $M$, and $N$ are diffeomorphic.

---

First my trial was using a natural projection between tangent bundle and manifold
\begin{align}
  &\pi_M : TM \rightarrow M  \\
  &\pi_N : TN \rightarrow N
\end{align}
what I know is this natural projection is smooth and surjective.

And from assumption there is a diffeomorphism $\phi : TM \rightarrow TN$. Using this I can construct a map from $M$ to $N$ as $\pi_N \circ \phi \circ \pi_M^{-1} : M \rightarrow N$, and my guess is this map is diffeomorphism.

But I am having trouble that showing this is indeed diffeomorphism. To see this first I need to show its bijectivity and smoothness. At this moment I am not sure whether $\pi^{-1}$ is smooth or not.

Is there any idea to show this composition map is diffeomorphism?

---

By the way is my approach right? If I am right, how can I prove $\pi_N \circ \phi \circ \pi_{M}^{-1}$ is a diffeomorphism?

Comment: If $v, w \in T_pM$, then $\pi_M(v) = \pi_M(w) = p$, so $\pi_M$ is not injective. In particular, $\pi_M$ is not invertible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think this is true, but I am sure that there are easier ways of showing it.

The tangent bundle of $S^7$ is trivial with respect to any of its smooth structures (see this [MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/58131/21564)). Let $M$ be an homotopy $7$-sphere (i.e. a manifold homeomorphic to $S^7$ but equipped with a non-standard smooth structure) which bounds a parallelizable manifold, and let $N$ be $S^7$ with its standard smooth structure. Then $TM$ is diffeomorphic to $M\times\mathbb{R}^7$ (with the product smooth structure) and $TN$ is diffeomorphic to $N\times\mathbb{R}^7$ (with the product smooth structure).

There is a theorem of Hirsch (see Theorem 5.4 of Smale's *On the structure of manifolds* for example), which states that if $M$ is a $n$-dimensional homotopy sphere which bounds a parallelizable manifold, then $M\times D^3$ is diffeomorphic to $S^n\times D^3$. In particular, $M\times D^3 \cong N\times D^3$. As $\mathbb{R}^3$ is diffeomorphic to $D^3$, we have

$$TM \cong M\times\mathbb{R}^7 \cong M\times\mathbb{R}^3\times\mathbb{R}^4 \cong M\times D^3\times\mathbb{R}^4 \cong N\times D^3\times\mathbb{R}^4 \cong N\times\mathbb{R}^3\times\mathbb{R}^4 \cong N\times\mathbb{R}^7 \cong TN$$

where $\cong$ is being used to denote 'diffeomorphic to', and throughout, the smooth structure on products is the product smooth structure.

Comment: I wanted to write such an answer, but I was lacking the argument provided by Hirsch's theorem... I wonder if Milnor's examples $M_1 = L(7,1) \times S^4$ and $M_2 = L(7,2) \times S^4$, which are nonhomeomorphic but  $h$-cobordant (so $M_1 \times \mathbb R$ and $M_2 \times \mathbb R$ are diffeomorphic by Mazur's trick) could provide another example...

Answer (score 5):

Consider (1) the trivial line bundle on the circle, i.e. the cylinder, and (2) the Möbius strip. They are not diffeomorphic (see [Moebius band not homeomorphic to Cylinder.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1149288/moebius-band-not-homeomorphic-to-cylinder)), but their tangent bundles are both diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^1\times \mathbb{R}^3$ (see [Tangent bundle of open annulus is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{R}^3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2231904/tangent-bundle-of-open-annulus-is-diffeomorphic-to-mathbbs1-times-mathbb/2231925#2231925) and [Tangent bundle of mobius strip is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{R}^3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2231940/tangent-bundle-of-mobius-strip-is-diffeomorphic-to-mathbbs1-times-mathbb/2231987#2231987)).