# Tangent bundle of mobius strip is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: tangent-bundle

This is a extension of my former question [[Tangent bundle of open annulus is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{R}^3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2231904/tangent-bundle-of-open-annulus-is-diffeomorphic-to-mathbbs1-times-mathbb])

Now i want to show the tangent bundle  $\mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{R}^3$.

I tried to construct the similar method, but having trouble with manipulation of mobius strip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the mobius strip $M$ be defined as the quotient space $\{(\theta,y)|\theta\in[0,\pi],y\in \mathbb{R}\}/(0,y)\sim(\pi,-y).$ Then the tangent bundle of $M$, $TM$, can be characterized as 
$$TM=\{(\theta,y,A\frac{d}{d\theta},B\frac{d}{dy})|\theta\in[0,\pi],y,A,B\in \mathbb{R}\}/(0,y,A,B)\sim(\pi,-y,A,-B).$$
Thus we construct the map $TM\to S^1\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{C}$ by 
$$(\theta,y,A,B)\mapsto (\theta,A,e^{i\theta}(y+\sqrt{-1}B)).$$
This map provides the desired diffeomorphism.